# Dynamically create ASP.NET button control using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I know this can be done for regular HTML buttons, but can asp:Button be created dynamically using jQuery?

Here's my button with an onclick that calls a server-side function:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnYesGPS" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="formButton" onclick="btnYesGPS_Click" />
```

Thank you for any guidance on this.

Comment: Think about what you are asking here. Where do server side controls get processed and rendered to the response stream? Where does jQuery live in the client browser?

Comment: tell us what you are trying to do, I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @negative, I'm getting a user's GPS location in a mobile browser, using W3C Geolocation via jQuery. I only want this button to appear if my app is able to get their location. The "btnYesGPS_Click" server-side function gets their Lat/Long and passes it to a web service.

Comment: You can create the button in code, apply a CSS class to hide the button and then using client side jQuery you can either remove the CSS class that is hiding it or use the .show() when the browser supports Geolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you have your server side logic already and just want to call it from client side, I see 2 options:

1. Hide asp.net button by default (`display:none`) and show it if GPS API is available
2. Call it via AJAX (WebMethod)

Personally I like the first option.

Comment: Awesome! #1 worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create ASP.NET controls with jQuery. They are server specific while jQuery is executed on client. They just belong so different and separated worlds.

Answer (score 0):

As Claudio mentioned you cannot create ASP.NET controls on the client side, however you can create elements on the client side which use jquery (or AJAX) to post back to the server side and perform some server side function.

If you give us some context to your question we may be able to provide a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You say you are posting to a webservice.
This can be done purely in javascript.

Add a `ScriptService` reference in your `ScriptManager`, and you should be able to call it from javascript. Then adding the button using jquery at client-side will suffice.

Adding a asp.net button at client side is not possible, and in this case not at all required.

If you need help refer here: [asp.net web services](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services)